# Python CSV function outputs blank CSV when not enough rows?

Tags: python, csv

I have a function which takes a list of custom objects, conforms some values then writes them to a CSV file.  Something really strange is happening in that when the list only contains a few objects, the resulting CSV file is always blank.  When the list is longer, the function works fine.  Is it some kind of weird anomaly with the temporary file perhaps?

I have to point out that this function returns the temporary file to a web server allowing the user to download the CSV.  The web server function is below the main function.

```
def makeCSV(things):
    from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
    # make the csv headers from an object
    headers = [h for h in dir(things[0]) if not h.startswith('_')]

    # this just pretties up the object and returns it as a dict
    def cleanVals(item):
        new_item = {}
        for h in headers:
            try:
                new_item[h] = getattr(item, h)
            except:
                new_item[h] = ''
            if isinstance(new_item[h], list):
                if new_item[h]:
                    new_item[h] = [z.__str__() for z in new_item[h]]
                    new_item[h] = ', '.join(new_item[h])
                else:
                    new_item[h] = ''
            new_item[h] = new_item[h].__str__()
        return new_item

    things = map(cleanVals, things)

    f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,sorted(headers),restval='',extrasaction='ignore')
    dw.writer.writerow(dw.fieldnames)
    for t in things:
        try:
            dw.writerow(t)
            # I can always see the dicts here...
            print t
        except Exception as e:
            # and there are no exceptions
            print e
    return f
```

Web server function:

```
    f = makeCSV(search_results)
    response = FileResponse(f.name)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = (
            "attachment; filename=export_%s.csv" % collection)
    return response
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: You create the file, you write into it, but you don't flush/close it. Therefore there may be data still not written to the disk.

Comment: `dw.writer.writerow` - are you sure that's not causing an error? Is there any particular reason you're using a temporary file, and not a `StringIO` object or similar, and just returning that?

Comment: I noticed that in `cleanVals()` you have bare `execpt:`. These should be avoid because they can make debugging problems even more difficult. Anyway, also consider what would happen if it were passed an item the doesn't have _any_ of the header attributes.

Comment: you should use str(z) instead of z.__str__()

Comment: @eumiro The idea of the temp file is that it closes in fact deletes itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing eumiro's answer: the file needs to be flushed.  Call f.flush() at the end of makeCSV().